# FPGA netlist parser

Tags: parsing, fpga, synthesis

In almost all synthesis tools for FPGA the output of HDL synthesis is some kind of EDIF format. E.g. in Synopsys such format has an extension .edn. However, this format is already FPGA-technology dependent (depends on the FPGA-type chosen before synthesis and its cells). Meanwhile in all synthesis tools I can see the gate level representation with simplest OR, AND gates and DFF, but the output files with this level of representation are encrypted.

I have to get the lowest level (AND,OR, DFF) netlist after FPGA synthesis process. Since generated EDIF files are technology/cells dependent, it is not very easy to parse them (I need the library of FPGA cell descriptions). Can I anyhow with any synthesis programs get lowest level netlist representation?

Thank you in advance for attention.

Comment: So if i understand it right, you want your FPGA design synthesized to simple logic gates rather than FPGA cells? If that is the case, you need to use an ASIC synthesis tool and not an FPGA.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a low-level gate netlist, you need to synthesise to a target library which has those elements.  Because FPGAs do not have raw gates within them, when the synthesiser targets them, it (somewhat obviously) creates elements which are available to it.

If you use an ASIC tool, that *will* use low level gates, as that is what that target has available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have understood *why* you need that edif netlist to be parsed.  But could it help you if you export the netlist after syntesis as VHDL or Verilog and parse that language?  Most synthesis tools have this export option to re-simulate the design after synthesis.